# " 'void' type not allowed here " Error message

Tags: java, void

```
public void runTheHorses()
{
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (!gameOver) {        
            raceDice.rollDice();
            if (horses[i].getMovingNumber() < raceDice.getSum()) {
                horses[i].updatePosition(raceDice.getDifference());
                if (horses[i].getPosition() >= finishLine) {
                    gameOver=true; 
                    winner=horses[i].getName();
                }
            }
            horses[i].setMovingNumber();
        }
    }
} // end method
```

I am making a horse race program. It is just a simple school exercise but when I try to compile it gives me an error message. In the line:

```
if (horses[i].getMovingNumber**()** < raceDice.getSum()){
```

Where it is bold, (the brackets after *.getMovingNumber*), it gives me the " 'void' type not allowed here" error message. I do not know what to do. The original method for *getMovingNumber* is:

```
private int movingNumber=4;

public int getMovingNumber()
{
    return movingNumber;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Please include the exact error, line number, etc.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - it's hard to help with only part of the problem.

Comment: As a style comment, but one that might make your problem clearer - it looks to me like you're overusing static variables.  For example, `rollDice()` really should just return the result, rather than just *putting* it somewhere and then needing the caller to call `getSum()`.  Ditto, `setMovingNumber()` should definitely take the "number" to set!  If you make these sort of changes, it is **much** easier to reason about how your program works, and avoid bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your `raceDice.getSum()` return type is void.

Comment: or probably `getMovingNumber()` is `void`

Comment: @AlexR `getMovingNumber()` returns an `int` as mentioned in the OP's post.

Comment: OK, so, the answer should be correct. The problem is in `getSum()`

Comment: There is still not enough information to know for sure. We dont know the type of the horses array, or the class that the getMovingNumber shown is from. But with the limited information we have this is the best guess, so +1

Comment: You are right there is not enough information. Its my bad but his answer is the right one